# What's is the actual reason that JavaScript is not enough to draw?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm looking for a pure JS library that allows to draw the mouse trail, but I cannot find anything pure but using canvas. Is there is a reason for that it could not be achieved? I'm on the wrong thoughts?

Comment: closed? really?

Comment: Can someone who voted to close this explain to Manu why. See the comment on my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you require Canvas is because the HTML DOM is an object model. There is not one element in HTML that allows arbitrary drawing (such as lines, per pixel, non-rectangular shapes) hence the requirement for using Canvas.

> Is there is a reason that I could not be achieved?

You could achieve this by creating an image at intervals of mouse movement that is a circle with a transparent background, for example, to simulate this. But canvas makes much more sense.

Comment: so, could I use the .mousemove jQ event to track every movement of the mouse on the document with event.pageX and event.pageY and set the values to a css position of a div?

Comment: Yes, create and append an element to the DOM and set it to `position: absolute`, setting the position to pageX/Y.

Comment: Great! You rock. It would be great if you could post it in jsfiddle or something like that, becasue I'm trying this: http://jsfiddle.net/4y2Ue/, but it does not work, and I'm entering on a self-destructive spiral.

Comment: @Manu: you're missing some + signs in your string concatenation, ..`top='posY';left`.. should be ..`top='+posY+';left`..

Comment: LOL what an idiot I am... fixed, but still not working!

Comment: @Sam could you please help me with this? I would like to know what I am doing wrong... And I really don't understand why stackexchange is becoming on a website where general question are strictly not allowed. Why they close everything that they annoy to his superior smartness? I mean, look at your answer, have been 6 times upvoted! Is really so important the answer, but to close the question? C'mon!

Comment: @Manu Stackoverflow.com will help with implementation concerns; programmers isn't for implementation between programmers and SO. I will try and look at it but I am very busy, you may get a quicker result on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Sam Ok, no worries, I will manage myself. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Manu no worries I will try and help at some stage, Stack Overflow is there specifically to help with implementation concerns so if you get stuck definitely post there.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, you're totally right, but the last 3 or 4 question I've posted on stackxchange (programmers, ux, server fault) have been closed, so I'm being frustrated for this policy that closes almost everything because I've readed the FAQ carefully and I have no clue why is downvoted or just closed.

Comment: It frustrates me too when I see questions getting closed. I suggest you take your case to Meta and ask why. Also if you get downvoted or closed, place a comment asking why.